# Finding a place in interdisciplinary sciences as someone who develops computational methods and algorithms for other fields?

Tags: changing-fields, code, interdisciplinary

I have a strong background in programming and I'm interested in solving computational problems in other areas like physics or economics. During my bachelor studies I have been involved in several research projects. However, my contribution was mostly limited to solving computational problems. The theoretical side of our research was done by others and I'm far away from really understanding it.

Is there a possibility for someone like me to find a suitable job in academics? Someone, who likes to apply computer science, but not just as a tool for solving simple problems. I'm thinking more in terms of developing algorithms or methods for other sciences, which can be reused and published.

Or is it the fate of computer scientists, who work interdisciplinarily,  to only be "used" for programming purposes and not contribute to their group's research any further?

Comment: You want us to help you to choose among computer science, physics and economics or possibly something else. Vote to close as this is a shopping question.

Comment: This is a request for advice. Maybe there's someone who has good or bad experiences with working in interdisciplinary fields such as I explained.

Comment: @sfat I've had a lot of good experiences working in interdisciplinary fields, and would be happy to offer information about doing so.  I'm afraid, however, that I cannot figure out what the answerable question is within what you have written.  What is is about interdisciplinary work that you are wondering?

Comment: @jakebeal I'm good at programming and applying my skills in new areas where I have little knowledge. But I am afraid that I will end up as *the IT guy* in research projects and will not be able to contribute beyond writing some code for someone else. Should I give up on my approach and focus on a single field? Or is it reasonable to only do the manual labour and let others think and write the bulk of the paper? Or is there some other solution?

Comment: @sfat If the computer component is just IT, it's not really interdisciplinary research.  Computer science is about a lot more than just coding.  Can I suggest you attempt to focus your question on this issue? It will then likely draw a number of useful answers for you.

Comment: _"I wanted to do research, but I noticed that I just wasn't good enough to do research in computer science."_ 1. How much _time_ have you spent trying to do research before noticing you are not good enough? Do you know that many famous scientists were not appreciated for years and even were told that they won't do any good in research (i.e., Einstein)? 2. Do you realize that, even if you've observed yourself for quite some time trying to do research, your conclusion that you aren't good enough for it might just be an indication of your _low self-esteem_, which is by definition **subjective**?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and seeing interesting answer would be nice. Upvote from me.

Comment: @jakebeal I see the problem in my initial post. I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh 1. The time I have spent with research in computer science is limited. The thing is, when I am around computer scientists, I am nobody and everybody else seems to have a better understanding of all the topics I am interested in. When I am around scientists from other areas, they actively ask for my advice with their problems and value my expertise. 2. That's a good point. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @sfat: Perhaps, your intuition is right (unless it's #2; and you're welcome) and it might be a good idea to try to engage in some non-pure-CS research, such as either interdisciplinary, or simply from different, but adjacent field (i.e. computational social science, econometrics, HCI). It is not easy to find yourself. I think that it takes both time and trying different directions. Good luck!

Comment: I've edited your title further, since what you are describing is not exactly "computer science" (and will reopen)

Comment: What point in your career are you at? Choosing a field (e.g. biology, physics, finance), making a PhD or couple of years postdoc there can make you a successful researcher of that field, IF you are willing to put in hard work to learn that field, too. If you just want to do software here and there, and do not have specialized knowledge of the field, most probably you will stuck in this situation.

Comment: @Greg I am currently thinking about either specializing in a specific field first with a master's program (e.g. biology, physics, finance), continuing with a computer science master or doing a PhD right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a concept of a research programmer, but it's pretty rare. My primary degrees are in maths and social sciences. While my PhD is in computer science, I use programming as a tool to do social science and am not really a great programmer. However, there is a lot of programming in the research projects that I tend to be involved in. For some projects, we would include a research programmer - someone with excellent programming skills who is doing methods development research. That is, the person would be developing new algorithms to solve some social science problem and implementing it. It sounds like this is what you are trying to find.

If so, such jobs do exist. However, they do not lead to a stable academic job since there's not a clear set of subjects that such a person can teach. Furthermore, the jobs are fairly rare.

Nevertheless, if you want this sort of job, you really need to work out what you ARE interested in. That is, economics or physics or whatever else. After that, you can think about what sort of problems are amenable to computational methods for their solutions. For example, look at computational social sciences (I do network science and agent-based modelling) and computational economics.

Comment: Good to hear that this is an actual job. However, I am actually looking for a more stable position in academics. My previous research topic also included agent-based modeling. What do you think of the future of this area? I hear it is not doing too good in central Europe, but currently rising in southeast Asia.

Comment: It is hard to tell what will happen in Asia in 5-10 years, however support positions like this tend to be rather weak for two reason: these are generally staff positions payed from grants, i.e money with fixed terms, also they are project oriented ie no long term direction that would easily  justify long term contracts.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you have a phenomenal career in store as an informaticist or data scientist/analyst. Perhaps look into such programs -- they will typically be newer. If you're not keen on another degree, you might even be able to secure a job doing data science now, for that matter.